# How to match patterns in a larger pattern using regular expression?

Tags: regex, sed

I have some code below and want to match only version strings that is defined when _AA(see below code) is defined.

```
#ifdef _AA
    #define VER 1.0.0.1
    #define VER2 1.0.0.1
#else
    #define VER 1.0.0.1
    #define VER2 1.0.0.1
#endif
```

I matched each version string by using this pattern:

```
[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+
```

But I don't know how to match only version strings in *_AA part* of the code.

c.f. I'm using gnu sed and final goal is to increment minor version number of matched version string.

Comment: sed works on line by line basis, use `awk`

Comment: How general does the code have to be?  Recognizing `#ifdef _AA` to `#else` in `sed` is easy: `sed -n -e '/^ifdef _AA/,/#else/{ ...whatever you were doing before plus p to print... }'`.  If you've got to recognize more variations of `#ifdef _AA`, then you're into writing a C preprocessor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match only within the `_AA` region, use an address specifier:

```
$ sed -n -r '/_AA/,/#else/ {/[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+/p}' file
    #define VER 1.0.0.1
    #define VER2 1.0.0.1
```

How it works:

- `-n`

  This tells sed not to print any lines unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `-r`

  This selects extended regex format.
- `/_AA/,/#else/`

  This is an address range selector.  It starts matching when it comes across a line with `_AA`.  It continues up to and including the first line which follows that matches `#else`.
- `/[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+/p`

  Of the lines matching the range selector, the ones matching your version regex are selected and printed.

  `[.]` is a good way to match a period.  While `.` is a normally the wildcard character, it loses it special meaning when in square brackets.

#### Incrementing the minor version number

You mentioned that final goal is to increment minor version number.   I would chose `awk` for this task because `sed` is not good at math:

```
$ awk -F. -v OFS=. '/_AA/,/#else/ {if (/[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+/) {$NF=$NF+1}}; {print}' file
#ifdef _AA
    #define VER 1.0.0.2
    #define VER2 1.0.0.2
#else
    #define VER 1.0.0.1
    #define VER2 1.0.0.1
#endif
```

How it works:

- `-F. -v OFS=.`

  This tells `awk` to use a period both for its input and output field separators.  With `.` as a field separator, it will be easy to increment the minor version number.
- `/_AA/,/#else/ {if (/[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+/) {$NF=$NF+1}};`

  This begins with `/_AA/,/#else/` which is an address range selector, just like the `sed` version.

  Among the lines within that address range, the `if` statement further selects lines that have a version number.  For those lines, the last field, `$NF`, is the minor version number and it is incremented by one.
- `{print}`

  Lastly, all lines are printed.

#### Editing a file in place

With `sed`, a file can be edited in place with the `-i` option (or `-i""` on OSX).

New versions of GNU `awk` (4.1.0 or better) also have an in-place editing option, similar to "sed -i".

With older versions of `awk`, one simulates in-place editing as follows:

```
awk  -F. -v OFS=. '/_AA/,/#else/ {if (/[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+/) {$NF=$NF+1}}; {print}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

`sed -i` and the newer `awk` do not really edit in-place.  They also write to a temporary file and then use it to overwrite the source file.  So, the in-place feature is merely a typing shortcut.

Comment: Thanks! I've never seen the range selector so explicitly defined (I actually have a batch file somewhere that does something like `sed -n -r '/start_token/ N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;s/find/replace/p' > dest_file.txt`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. But, how can I output the awk result into the same file(input file)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to other suggestions; using a Perl one-liner to print the version strings between those patterns.

```
perl -ne 'if (/_AA/../#else/) { print unless /_AA/ or /#else/ }' file
    #define VER 1.0.0.1
    #define VER2 1.0.0.1
```

If you want the leading whitespace removed:

```
perl -ne 'if (/_AA/../#else/) { s/^\s+// and print unless /_AA/ or /#else/ }' file
#define VER 1.0.0.1
#define VER2 1.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(\d+\.){3}\d+
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/pU4kA7/1)**